# AngularJS | Card Element doesn't access API for Details View

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api, twitter-bootstrap-3

In our Application, we have an API we consume in order to get details for a specific card. Their `id` in short. The `endpoint` and `id` are correct and can be clicked by numerous other points in the application. Even from inside the screen. Card View(Cannot Click) vs Table View(Can Click), the same endpoint.

Here is my Code. We use AngularJS, Redux, Bootstrap 3 in our App. This is the endpoint we want to hit:

```
href="#/services/somethings/{{something.info.id}}"
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row pt10 pl10 pr10" ng-if="!showTableView">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 smpl10 {{ !($index % 3 == 0) ? 'pl0' : ''}}"
                    ng-repeat="something in somethings | orderBy: 'info.id' | filter : search">
                    <a ng-if="somthing.else" href="#/services/somethings/{{something.info.id}}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #616161">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                      ...........
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you tell me why I cannot click the damn card to go to the details page? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the <a> display correctly in the screen?

Comment: Yes. To tell you the truth I found the problem. Inside the first <a> tag, I had another one. That made a lot of problems. I will post my own solution later so you guys can see my dumb code.